# SiteCore 6.3+: Long wait time before content changes is visible after publishing

Tags: sitecore, publishing

When doing content changes and publishing it, it usually takes between 5 to 10 minuttes before the changes becomes vissible.

Ive tried changing some of the scheduling agent times in web.config, but this didnt change anything.

Comment: How is you environment configured? Do you have separate content delivery and manipulation servers? Do you use lucene or any other search engines to look for articles? Do you use any custom cache mechanisms?

Comment: Or are you using any sort of CDN like Akamai to help deliver content? Also, is there anything in the Sitecore logs around the time you publish or the time when you see the change go live?

Comment: No server separation (that I know of, its a default installation), no lucene, no custom caching. Currently we dont use a CDN.

Comment: Is there anything strange in the logfiles? In case you have Sitecore Rocks: If you use Sitecore Rocks's Job Viewer when you're publishing, do you see anything strange happening then? (i.e. long running custom jobs kicking off before the cache is cleaned)

Comment: I would guess that your caches are not clearing correctly. Are you running in a multi-site environment? What are the `name` attributes of your `<sites>` elements and did you add them to the `<event name="publish:end">` HtmlCacheClearer handler?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the name of your site to the HtmlCacheClearer publish:end event in the web.config or in the SiteDefinition.config in the /App_Config/Include/ folder.

```
<event name="publish:end">
        <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
          <sites hint="list">
            <site>website1</site>
            <site>website1</site>
          </sites>
        </handler>
      </event>
```

This event is trigger after a publish and it clears the Sitecore HTML cache. If this cache isn't cleared, you don't see your changes until the app_pool is recycled or the cache is cleared manually or through the scheduler.

If you are using a separated CMS- and ContentDelivery server, you also need the `publish:end:remote` event with the same sites.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to lower the time between publish and visibility by lowering:

```
<!-- Time between checking for scheduled tasks waiting to execute -->
<frequency>00:00:10</frequency> <!-- 00:05:00 -->
```

and

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:30"> <!-- 00:10:00 -->
            <param desc="database">core</param>
            <param desc="schedule root">/sitecore/system/tasks/schedules</param>
            <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
        </agent>
```